# PHP array sorting cant get the correct output

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

can any one help me how to get the sorting of the numbers;

```
num1 = 1
num2 = 1
num3 = 3
num4 = 5


 $values = array($_POST["num1"] => 1, $_POST["num2"] => 2,$_POST["num3"] => 3,$_POST["num4"] =>4);
    asort($values);
    foreach($values as $key => $val){
    echo "<br>$key = $val<br>";
    }
```

The num1 is not printed..
and i got an out put of

1 = 2

3 = 3

4 = 4

how can i got the output complete like this?

1 = 1 | 1 = 2 | 3 = 3 | 4 = 4

Comment: you cannot assign an array key more than once!

Comment: awts T_T how can i solve that?

Answer (score 0):

You have the **key => value** pair the wrong way round in your array, hence why your key for 1 gets overwritten.

Try replacing your $values = ... line with this:

```
$values = array(1 => $_POST["num1"], 2 => $_POST["num2"], 3 => $_POST["num3"], 4 => $_POST["num4"]);
```

Comment: what if the $val value is also inputted and there is a duplicated value,, is there a way to get the output i want?

Comment: have you tried with the newly arranged array I posted above? Nothing should get overwritten as lone as none of the numbers on the left of the => are the same...